# Implementation of a simple Z-Buffer in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, zbuffer

I have a 3D point cloud and I project the pixels to an image plane. Since some 3D points get mapped to the same pixel, I only want the pixel with the lowest Z-value to my camera. I use a Z-Buffer - a float array - to keep track of my depth values. Here's some pseudocode:

```
// Initialize z-Buffer with max depth (99999.9f)
// Go through every point of point cloud...
// Project Point (x,y,z) to image plane (u,v) 
int newIndex = v*imgWidth+u;
float oldDepth = zbuffer[newIndex];

if (z < oldDepth){
  zbuffer[newIndex] = z; // put z value in buffer
  outputImg[newIndex] = pointColor[i]; // put pixel in resulting image
}
```

I have a perfectly working single-core CPU version of this.

The cuda version looks fine and is extremely fast, but **only the areas where a z-test play a role** are very "streaky", which means that some background points are overwriting the foreground pixels, I think. Also, when I look at the color image I see random color streaks with colors that are not present in the image.

The CUDA version looks more like this:

```
//Initialize, kernel, project, new coordinates...

const float oldDepth = outputDepth[v * outputMaxWidth + u];

if (z < oldDepth){
  outputDepth[v * outputMaxWidth + u] = z;
  const int inputColorIndex = yIndex * inputImageStep + 3*xIndex;
  const int outputColorIndex = yIndex * outputImageStep + 3*xIndex;
  outputImage[outputColorIndex] = inputImage[inputColorIndex]; //B
  outputImage[outputColorIndex + 1] = inputImage[inputColorIndex + 1]; //G
  outputImage[outputColorIndex + 2] = inputImage[inputColorIndex + 2]; //R
}
```

I think that the concurrency is a problem here. One thread may write the nearest z-value of this pixel in the Z-Buffer, but just at the same time another thread reads the old value and overwrites the correct value.

How do I prevent this in CUDA?

Edit1:
Reducing the block size from (16,16) to (1,1) will result in less streaky patterns, but it will look like 1 pixel holes.

Edit2:
Here's a minimal example:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

cudaError_t insertToZBuffer(int *z, const int *a, unsigned int size);

__global__ void zbufferKernel(int *z, const int *a)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    if (a[i] < z[0]){
        z[0] = a[i]; //  all mapped to pixel index 0        
    }    
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        const int arraySize = 5;
        const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 7, 3, 40, 5 }; // some depth values which get mapped all to index 0
        int z[arraySize] = { 999 }; // large depth value

        insertToZBuffer(z, a, arraySize);

        printf("{%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n", z[0], z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4]);
        cudaDeviceReset();

    }   
    return 0;
}

cudaError_t insertToZBuffer(int *z, const int *a, unsigned int size){
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_z = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_z, size * sizeof(int));
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_z, z, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    zbufferKernel<<<1, size >>>(dev_z, dev_a);
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();   
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(z, dev_z, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_z);
    cudaFree(dev_a);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

The value from z at index 0 should be 1 because it is the lowest value, but it is 5, which is the last value of a.

Comment: Could you please post the code containing full kernel and it's invocation parameters (block, grid dimensions) ?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.pastebin.com/prEuzXbQ

Comment: please edit your question so that it contains a [mcve] which one could copy, paste and compile without any further modification

Comment: @m.s. I've added a minimal, copy-pastable example for a new CUDA 7.5 Runtime project.

Comment: Your code has a memory race within the kernel. It isn't possible to find a minima in parallel in the way you have written.

Comment: Yes, this is also what I assumed. Well, how I need to write it then? I am new to CUDA.

Comment: there are a few standard ways: [parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) and [atomics](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3101-Atomic-Memory-Operations.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I solved it thanks to the comments:

I've used atomicCAS (casting floats to ints) to write to my z-buffer if it has a smaller z value. When the current thread has a larger z value, I simply return. In the end I synchronize all the remaining threads (__syncthreads()), which have written to the buffer and check if their z value was the final one. If that was indeed true, I write the point color to my pixel value at this position.

Edit: I should have used just atomicMin...

Comment: `__syncthreads()` should not be used when you have some threads that may have returned before they reach the `__syncthreasd()`.  This is covered in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) and there are relatively straightforward ways to satisfy this code-correctness requirement.  Its not entirely clear to me why you need the `__syncthreads()` anyway based on your description.  It appears that you expect the z values to be unique amongst the checked threads.